# How to send multiple emails to the same address?

Tags: email, sendgrid

1. I'd like to know how to send multiple emails to the same address. I need it to create an email campaign sytem for an activism organisation. No marketing stuff whatsoever. 
   People will write their own content, click "send" and an email will be sent to a specific set of addresses. The sender wouldn't have to add nothing beyond the email content.

I don't want to have the organisation ip blacklisted and stuff like that.

2. Examples: Avaaz.
3. I'm not asking how to do that technically in PHP/other, I'm asking how to do it correctly without being blocked and recognized as spam.
4. Is using SendGrid could be the answer?
5. Tried to google it and search for it here but couldn't find something, but please refer me if I'm mistaken.

Please advise

Thanks in advance